# How to implement Cross domain SSO with OPENAM

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, openam

I want to implement single sign on application in JAVA.

I don't know how to configure OPENAM as a Identity Provider.

And I used Websphere application server for Service Provider.

Can anyone help me for Implement SSO between OPENAM and Websphere application server.

Comment: this question is probably better suited for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may look at

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1307_lansche/1307_lansche.html

It seems IBM WebSphere has a SAML TAI which can act as an SP.